# log file is access denied even I am an administrator

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2012-r2, permissions, file-permissions

I try to open a mysql slow log file in windows server 2012 R2. Even I open notepad as administrator, it still says "access denied". I check the mode of the file in powershell and found that the file is haveing an "a" attribute. How can I read the file? I even cannot copy the file.

Comment: The `A` flag is for _Archive_ and has nothing to do with permissions. Obviously the NTFS permissions are not set for your admin user, but as you are an admin, you can just set them to be (at least) readable for you. Careful, though, don't delete MySQL's permissions so it can't log anymore.

Comment: If MySQL has the log file open for exclusive access, you won't be able to open it regardless of the permissions.